# Moving Web-parts - OldServer 2007 to NewServer 2007

Tags: web-part, migration

I have a Sharepoint 2007 server that I'm setting up for a client. They have an old Sharepoint 2007 site collection that contains several web parts. They don't have the solution (sln) files for all the web parts, all they have is the deployed web parts on their old site and they only want to move some of the web parts (and content) not all of them.

Is it possible to backup the old web parts and deploy them in the new server (or similar to achieve the same result)? If so, could someone please advise on the best strategy for doing this.

(Note: I have been using Gary Lapointe's stsadm extensions (http://stsadm.blogspot.com/2007/08/stsadm-commands_09.html) for moving the content across, but there doesn't appear to be any commands for doing this with web parts.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, you just need the webpart dll's in the bin or gac for the webparts to work correctly.

If you want them to be able to add some of the old webparts, then you can export the dwp or webpart files from the webpart gallery and import them into the new site collection's webpart gallery.

Comment: Hi Steve, Thanks for your help. I eventually worked out that you can navigate to _catalogs/wp in SPD2007 - then select all webpart files,  copy, then paste into the same location on the target site. This allows the users to add the web parts using the SP user interface although it does lose the grouping that existed in the source site (i.e. how the web parts were grouped in the "Add Web Parts - Webpage Dialog"). Now they are all grouped under "Miscellaneous" - i'm not overly worried about this. This saved me having to export/import each web part individually which would have taken ages (50+).